# Using two arrays when I know I should be using a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var X = $('p:first');
$(X).each(function(index,Element) {
    tbody = '';
    tr = '<tr><td>' + index + '</td><td>';
    var arr = [];
    var typ = [];
    for (prop in Element) {
        arr[arr.length] = prop;
        typ[arr.length] = typeof Element[prop];
    }
    arr = arr.sort();
    for (var i=0,ii=arr.length;i<ii;i++) {
        tbody += tr + arr[i] + '</td><td>' + typ[i] + '</td></tr>';
        tr = '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>';
    }
});
$('body').append('<table class="border">' + tbody + '</table>');
```

Q: How can this be rewritten to eliminate the typ array and instead make arr a two-dimensional array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it an array of objects:

```
    var arr = [];
    for (prop in Element) {
      arr.push({ name: prop, type: typeof Element[prop] });
    }
```

You'll have to change the ".sort()":

```
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.name > b.name ? 1 : a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an array of objects instead? Something like:

```
 var arr = []

 for ( prop in Element) {
   arr[ arr.length].property = prop;
   arr[ arr.length].type = type of Element[prop];
 }
```

The only disadvantage of this: you will have to provide your own sorting function.